# My restaurant review project needs to work offline, but my local simple server shows 404 error

Tags: server, local

I am working on a project for Udacity. I am supposed to start a a simple HTTP server for my directory, but when I am trying to view the file on http://localhost:8000/ I see a different file and my terminal shows file not found error. I'm sure I must've done something, but I don't know [image]how to fix this. Please HELP!

Comment: not sure how you have this setup but assuming you’re fetching index (or whatever page) make sure the relative paths in the html are correct

Comment: Yes, I am fetching index.html. So are you saying that instead of http://localhost:8000/ should be http://localhost:8000/mywebsite/index.html?

Comment: not specifically .. what does the <head> section in your index.html look like?

Comment: <head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Normalize.css for better cross-browser consistency -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" src="//normalize-css.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/normalize.css" />
  <!-- Main CSS file -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
  <title>Restaurant Reviews</title>
</head>

Comment: so it looks like you’re missing the link to your javascript `sw.js`

Comment: Ok, does the sw.js have to be in the head, not in the body?

Comment: anyway, my local server seems to open a different file, not the one I need..

Comment: oh no you're right, it can be in the body.. i'm assuming it is? also i misread (i am on phone) but i can see now that sw.js is found but the stylesheet is not

Comment: what is the URL you are typing into your browser? is `sw.js` the first file that is found? i dont know because can't see but i _think_ `sw.js` is appending `/Restaurant-Reviews-App/` to all requests, ie, `index.html` becomes `/Restaurant-Reviews-App/index.html` and etc.. if that path doesn't exist then you get that 404

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. Brackets was running its own server, so my app was running on that server instead of the local server I started. Pain in my ass. Thanks for your help